# Is it possible to use html in php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use html code in php but its saying sytnax error unexpected '<' is it possible to use html in php below is the code

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['searchquery']) && isset($_GET['searchquery']) != "")
{
 if($_GET['select']=="empty"){
<html>  // syntax error saying unexpected '<'
<head>
    <div id="templatemo_content">

        <div class="templatemo_box">
      <input value="<?php echo "PLEASE SELECT CATEGORY  "; ?>"  />
  </div>
 </div>
 </head>
</html>
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No you have html tags inside php block. This is why you are getting :

> unexpected '<'

PHP is considering the < of the `<html>` as an illegal character 
The following should work:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['searchquery']) && isset($_GET['searchquery']) != "")
{
 if($_GET['select']=="empty"){
 ?>
        <html>  
        <head>
            <div id="templatemo_content">

                <div class="templatemo_box">
              <input value="<?php echo "PLEASE SELECT CATEGORY  "; ?>"  />
          </div>
         </div>
         </head>
        </html>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's extremely possible.

```
<html>
<body>
 <?php
     print("<b>This is how you html in php</b>");
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use echo to print the html out of php, or end the php and start the html

Echo option

```
Echo "<html> </html>";
```

Starting stopping

```
<?php my php code starts here ?>
<html> my html is here 
<?php more php code here ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use HTML in PHP directly. If you want to mix PHP and HTML (which is recommended only in templates by the way), you have to use the PHP start and end tags every time you switch between PHP and HTML:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['searchquery']) && isset($_GET['searchquery']) != "")
{
 if($_GET['select']=="empty"){
//use this tag to end the PHP part:
?>
<html>
<head>
    <div id="templatemo_content">

        <div class="templatemo_box">
      <input value="<?php echo "PLEASE SELECT CATEGORY  "; ?>"  />
  </div>
 </div>
 </head>
</html>
<?php //you have to use this
}
}
?>
```